# Can not make a tag in SVN repo from command line

Tags: svn, command-line, copy

What I want to do:
I have checked out WC in current folder ("App", which is not SVN repository folder), sources were built and I want to make a tag in repository based on revisions in my WC

I run the following command (in "App" folder)
"C:\Program Files\CC\server\svn\svn.exe" copy *.* https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/tags/2009_10_07-0006 --username XXXXXXX --password XXXXXXXX --non-interactive -m "Production version 0006 at 2009-10-07 - 17:03:39 by "

And get the following error message and no tag added in repository:
svn: Skipping argument: '_svn' ends in a reserved name
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/tags/2009_10_07-0006' path not found

Any ideas? what's wrong
SVN Client - 1.5.4
SVN server version 1.5.x

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using two inconsistent subversion clients: one using `_svn` as the folder name for the metadata, and the other one `.svn`. If you also have been using TortoiseSVN: it's an install time option. Otherwise, the `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK` environment variable may have been set when the checkout was made.

Comment: Martin,<br/>
Let add more details.
 - At first I checkout sources using the following command:<br/>
"C:\Program Files\CC\server\svn\svn.exe" checkout https://svnhost.com/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/trunk App -q --username XXXXX --password XXXXXX --non-interactive --force<br/>
 - then I build the project and if build successful<br/>

Comment: - want to tag it in SVN by command listed in my initial post:<br/>
"C:\Program Files\CC\server\svn\svn.exe" copy . https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/tags/2009%5F10%5F07-0006 --username XXXXXXX --password XXXXXXXX --non-interactive -m "Production version 0006 at 2009-10-07 - 17:03:39 by "<br/>
<br/>
So it means I don't use different clients (TortoiseSVN is also installed on the host).<br/>
Let me check this magic environment variable additionally.

Comment: yes, I have such variable set to SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK=*

How should it be set to allow me making changes in SVN repo?

Comment: As I got it from http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/asp-dot-net-hack.txt

That's not the issue in my case, I checkout sources with this variable and try to make tag.

Comment: Colleagues, 
The issue is closed - I fixed the command 
from "C:\Program Files\CC\server\svn\svn.exe" copy *. * https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/tags/20091007-0006 --username XXXXXXX --password XXXXXXXX --non-interactive"
to "C:\Program Files\CC\server\svn\svn.exe" copy App https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/TM1/Sources/tags/20091007-0006 --username XXXXXXX --password XXXXXXXX --non-interactive" running it from parent folder

Comment: It fixed the issue, as I understand SVN cannot hanfle "*. *" wildcard
P.S. This site replaces * . * (in case no spaces added) with just one dot (".") in the posts!!!